# Thin server process dies after a few second after start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, proxy, webserver, thin

The situation: When I start thin from the root dir of my rails app with `sudo /etc/init.d/thin start`, which I have set up so that it runs 3 instances on port 3000, 3001 and 3002, while looking at it in `$ htop`, I can see how the thin servers are up and running for a few seconds and then disappears, leading to a 502 Bad Gateway, because nginx is setup to map traffic to it.

So why cant they not keep running?

I'm following this guide, btw: http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/ubuntu-hardy-nginx-rails-and-thin